# Get all projects in SVN that have svn:externals to a certain repository

Tags: windows, svn

I have many projects in SubVersion that have an `svn:externals` reference to a Core project (let's say they have an svn:externals property pointing a local path *`/Components`* to `http://svn/repos/core_components`).

Now, I want to get a list of all the projects/folders that have an svn:externals reference to that Core project. Is there an SVN command/script/tool to perform that? (I am on Windows)

Answer (score 1):

<strike>If your externals definitions are scattered throughout the repository-tree - you'll have a Bad Day (tm): you have togo recursively over all nodes in each you repository, for Windows it isn't an easiest task.</strike>
For recursive testing repo-tree add `-R` option to used command

If you have common place for all externals in repo (root /of trunk/ is good candidate), you can use

`svn propget svn:externals` (check only one property)

or

`svn proplist -v` (get all properties with values)

you'll get grepable output (or none in case of propget and missing externals)

**Samples:**

- Non-recursive propget for path with externals

`>svn propget svn:externals`

`https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/subversion-trouble-shooting/trunk/lib lib`

- Non-recursive verbose proplist for path with externals

`>svn proplist -v`

`Properties on '.':`

`svn:externals`

`https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/subversion-trouble-shooting/trunk/lib lib`

- Recursive propget for path with externals

`>svn propget svn:externals -R`

`tags\1.0.1 - -r 2 https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/subversion-trouble-shooting/trunk/lib@2 lib`

`trunk - https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/subversion-trouble-shooting/trunk/lib lib`

- Non-recursive propget for path without externals

`>svn propget svn:externals`